# How do you connect Service Now with Forge to create a new BIM 360 project?

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I've used the process documented here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360.project.setup.tool to automate creating a new project HUB. We ask our users to fill a form on [Service Now](https://www.servicenow.com/) for each new project. My question is: Has anyone had any success linking the Service Now API to Forge? So that the variables that are filled by the end user on the Service Now form are used by Forge to create a new project HUB. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Service Now, but I've created integration with internal system.
Integration depends on what you need.
1.You can create a plugin for Service Now(If it is supports adding plugins) ,and create an app to fill into info that you need to create new project in Bim360(project name,users,etc.)
2.If you need to create a new project based on your info in Service Now,you should take Service Now Api, read all info that you need and then pass it to Autodesk Forge Api to create new project.